# Github pull command returns "repository ... not found"

Tags: git, github

I have a "dev" branch we use for staging. I have another branch I'm working in to create my feature. I want to pull changes on dev then push pull request my branch back into "dev".

I'm using the Github desktop app for Mac to push changes and synch to my branch. I tried doing `git pull origin master` and `git pull` but I always get the repo isn't found.

I've validated my SSH in listed in settings.

Comment: Is your remote called `origin`? The name of the remotes isn't set in stone, they are added by whoever sets up git for that folder. I've also seen `upstream` used in some cases.

Comment: my working branch was created from the "dev" branch. If I use `git pull dev` i get `fatal: 'dev' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: Run `git remote` while inside a git repository's folder and you'll see the remotes that are added. Use the one it outputs in place of `origin` in your command.

Comment: tried that and `origin` is returned. When I attempt `git pull origin` I'm told the repository is `not found`

Comment: Then your repository probably needs to be set up again. As it is right now, your question cannot be answered.